# I wrote RegCreateKeyEx () but it failed. what is its cause?

Tags: c, winapi

I tried to write a program to register the startup program(use Registry)

It will run .. (I used Win32api, c language, Visual Studio Community 2019)

It should print "success" but print "fail".

There's no error message (?) And I think it's not a permission problem. what is its 
cause?

```
wchar_t path[1024];
    wchar_t regSubKeyPath[1000] = L"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run";
    wchar_t valueName[100] = L"hello";
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, path, 1000);
    if (RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, regSubKeyPath, 0, NULL,
        REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &hKey, NULL) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("fail");
    }
    else {
        RegSetValueEx(hKey, valueName, 0, REG_EXPAND_SZ, (BYTE*)path, wcslen(path));
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
        printf("success");
    }
```

Comment: you even not check code returned by `RegCreateKeyEx`

Comment: The return value is an error code. What is the value of that error code? .

Comment: and `L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run";` must be - are you not got warning from compiler here ? and you ignore it ?

Comment: yes.  I not got warning from compiler.

Comment: error code is ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER(87) Is it administrator rights?

Comment: Did you replace the single backslashes with double backslashes?

Comment: Yes. Oh ... again I see code 5 (access denied). I will fix it.

Comment: Access denied is because you need admin rights